# How do I edit a variable declared in the root contained within the frame of a movie clip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I have a main scene called Game. In that scene, I have a movieclip called Shop. Inside that movieclip called shop, I have another movie clip called upgradeweapon2. Inside upgradeweapon2, I have a button called "upgradeweaponpb".
I am working in actionscript, in the frame of the movie clip upgradeweapon2. I am trying to edit a variable called "weaponlvl" that was declared in Game. A picture to show what I mean:
http://gyazo.com/96b04ab89ea4a589bee560d53d165b03.png

I am getting the following error: Access of undefined property weaponlvl.

Please tell me there is a way around this... I know weaponlvl is defined in the root scene, game, but is there a way to make the declaration valid across levels of MovieClips, or at least a way to transfer the values accross?

Here is the code I am trying to add:

```
    stop();
    upgradepb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, upgradeweapon5);
    function upgradeweapon5(event:MouseEvent):void{ 
        weaponlvl++;
    }
```

EDIT: Alright I simplified my code, It's just a movieclip, not two layers. But still the same error. Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`weaponlvl` is on the frame of `upgradeweapon2.upgradeweaponpb`;  it is not on the root layer, so therefore in action script it will not make sense.  You have two options:

Get `weaponlvl` through `MovieClip(root).weaponlvl` or `this.parent.parent` (which is also the root).

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish I waited a little and didn't completely undo what I did. I'll try what you're saying now. =)